# Can't make UI Scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scroll, scrollview

I am trying to make a Login Activity for Android Application. App is working fine in Potrait mode but in landscape mode, UI can't accommodate completely and thus part of UI is not visible.I have referred to all the related SO question but none helped.
Device- Motorola X Style Marshmallow

**Code for activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignupActivity"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_login" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Code for content_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#1E1E24"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".SignupActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_font"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:text="Login Activity"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_view_width"
        android:background="@color/photo_border"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title_font"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:text="Hey ! This is a sample App for Login Activity"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_main_marginTop_35"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/third"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_marginTop_15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:hint="@string/enter_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_spinner_width"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_marginTop_15" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            style="@style/NavigateButton"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_main_marginTop_35"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code for toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/background_textview"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

To solve this, I am trying to make UI scrollable so that user can scroll to part not visible in landscape mode.
**What I have tried** -
1. I have tried putting below inside Scrollview

> include layout="@layout/content_login" />

2 I have tried putting above inside Linear Layout and then Linear layout inside Scrollview.
And there are many other things I played with but none helped.
Please help me in this.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the root element of content_login.xml as `ScrollView`.
You can have nested layouts with the current relative layout within a new scroll view.

Alternatively, you can fix the orientation of the activity to `portrait` using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` under the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml if its not an issue.

Also, consider using `ConstraintLayout`, it eliminates the hassle of dealing with nested layouts.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your first method worked with some minor changes.

Comment: glad to be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SignupActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".SignupActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_font"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:text="Login Activity"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/first"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_view_width"
            android:background="@color/photo_border"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_below="@id/second"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title_font"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:text="Hey ! This is a sample App for Login Activity"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_main_marginTop_35"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/third"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_marginTop_15"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit_name"
                android:hint="@string/enter_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_spinner_width"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/contacting_post_staff_marginTop_15" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                style="@style/NavigateButton"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_main_marginTop_35"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Try this, add all the padding, margins, height, width etc as you want and all the layout constraints